This is where/what we have come to
Recently I found out that remarks I had made about the Duchess of Sussex were the subject of debate on talk radio. I had pointed out to Piers Morgan, who finds it hard to leave the topic alone, that Meghan had to “learn” what it was like to be black in our society. She herself claimed that she had never been treated as a black person before coming to the UK. Her own mother said in a documentary that she regretted never having talked to Meghan about race. The discussion branded me a racist — yet the programme’s producers didn’t invite me to explain my views.
This is where we have come to: when a person of colour finds themselves, in effect, cancelled for being sympathetic to another person of colour.
https://www.standard.co.uk/comment/trevor-phillips-racism-freedom-speech-meghan-duchess-of-sussex-piers-morgan-b1104945.html
Can I also say:

This is what we have come to.

Or just

This is where we have come.


The original sounds very strange to me.  To me, "this is what we have come to" sounds much more idiomatic than "where we have come to."

There may be variations between dialects, but I feel confident in saying that most native speakers (certainly British English) would say "this is what we have come to", when said about situations. Of course, if said literally about a physical location then 'where' would be right.
However, a very similar idiom is "this is where we are at", and this is said about situations. Perhaps the two have become conflated?

The 'at' on the "this is where we are [at]" is optional. I would hazard the variant with where is more common in American English, but the other isn't unheard of and would be readily understood.
